# Compare rows of two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, the first is the data I currently have in the database, the second would be a file that might have changed fields:
`name` and/or `cnpj` and/or `create_date`

Based on that, I need to create a third dataframe with only the rows that have undergone some kind of change, as in the example of the expected output.

The key to making the comparisons needs to be:
`id_account`

Dataframe 1:

| id_account | name | cnpj | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Agency Criss | 10203040 | 2022-05-30 |
| 20 | Agency Angel | 11213141 | 2022-05-30 |
| 30 | Supermarket Mario Bros | 12223242 | 2022-05-30 |
| 40 | Agency Mister M | 13233343 | 2022-05-30 |
| 50 | Supermarket Pokemon | 14243454 | 2022-05-30 |
| 60 | Supermarket of Dreams | 15253580 | 2022-05-30 |

Dataframe 2:

| id_account | name | cnpj | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Supermarket Carol | 80502030 | 2022-05-30 |
| 20 | Agency Angel | 11213141 | 2022-05-30 |
| 30 | Supermarket Mario Bros | 12223242 | 2022-05-30 |
| 40 | Supermarket Magical | 60304050 | 2022-05-30 |
| 50 | Supermarket Pokemon | 14243454 | 2022-05-30 |
| 60 | Supermarket of Dreams | 90804050 | 2022-05-30 |

Expected output:

| id_account | name | cnpj | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Supermarket Carol | 80502030 | 2022-05-30 |
| 40 | Supermarket Magical | 60304050 | 2022-05-30 |
| 60 | Supermarket of Dreams | 90804050 | 2022-05-30 |

How can I do this? I've looked for a few ways, but I'm confused by the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data has same columns, but different number of rows, this is one possible solution:

```
res = (pd.concat([df1,df2])
       .drop_duplicates(keep=False)
       .drop_duplicates(subset='id_account', keep='last')
      )
```

Output:

```
   id_account                   name      cnpj create_date
0          10      Supermarket Carol  80502030  2022-05-30
3          40    Supermarket Magical  60304050  2022-05-30
5          60  Supermarket of Dreams  90804050  2022-05-30
```

Answer (score 2):

If your two dataframes have the same columns and the same number of rows, you can check equate them and use `any(axis=1)` to find rows where any columns changes:

```
new_df = df2[(df1 != df2).any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   id_account                   name      cnpj create_date
0          10      Supermarket Carol  80502030  2022-05-30
3          40    Supermarket Magical  60304050  2022-05-30
5          60  Supermarket of Dreams  90804050  2022-05-30
```

Comment: In that case the indexes may be different, could it be a problem?

Comment: @Caroline is `id_account` your index?

Comment: And it may be that there are not the same number of lines @richardec

Comment: you can drop the index for the boolean check  @CarolineLeite thanks richardec you're very kind!